# JWT authorization in nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, jwt, nuxt.js

I have a problem with authorization via JWT using nuxt. I want to restrict access to specific routes for users that don't have JWT token. The most proper place to check authorization in nuxt is middleware, but I can not access localStorage inside of it. I tried to set `mode: "spa"` in nuxt.config.js and to check `if (process.browser)` condition in middleware to get access to localStorage in middleware, but this condition is false for every request. So, are there any options to check JWT token existance in middleware? Should I store JWT token in localStorage? If not, where should I store it?

Comment: This template will help, https://github.com/lcherone/starter-template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to use `process.client` instead of `process.browser` to check if its a client or not. See [docs here](https://nuxtjs.org/api/context/)

> isClient  Boolean Client & Server Boolean to let you know if you're
>   actually renderer from the client-side **(deprecated. use**
>   **process.client)**.

Second if u set `mode: spa` it always will be true, so this check only makes sense in universal mode.

Third you can store token both in localstorage and cookie, thats how [nuxt-auth](https://github.com/nuxt-community/auth-module) module is done. Take a loot at it, probably u will be able to use it instead of writing your own implementation, or at least you will have some ideas how its implemented

Comment: Do I understand correctly that localStorage in  `nuxt-auth` module does not work on the server?

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько nuxt auth use universal storage. On server it use cookies to get info, on client it use both cookies and localstorage. Localstorage not available on server